# Bootstrap grid issue with fullpage.js, image goes out of column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, fullpage.js

I tried to put image in `<div class="col-md-4">`with the class: img-responsive, but the image goes out of the `<div>`. The html markup works fine in a new pen without fullpage.js. So I am wondering it is somewhat conflicted with fullpage.js.

The link is here:
Please check the 3rd page: http://codepen.io/hieverest/pen/dNgGjN?editors=1010

The markup works fine in a new pen: http://codepen.io/hieverest/pen/MJzbRe?editors=1010

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This has nothing to do with **fullPagejs**. You're seeing this because of this rule in your CSS `#section2 img { margin: 20px 0 0 52px; }. If you apply your CSS to both CodePens the same behaviour occurs with or without fullPagejs.

Comment: OMG, that's the problem! That's the code left from the fullpage.js demo. I forgot to delete. Thank you so much!! I was so frustrating to get stuck there.